# How to use YouTube API v3 to get user's videos

Tags: youtube-api

The **user** in question only registered and uploaded some videos. It does have *playlist*, nor *channel*. But when I use [youtube.channels.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list), I still got one channel returned.

**I assume it is the default channel to list all videos.**

I tried to use [youtube.search.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list) with **channelID** and **publishedAfter** critiera to search all the videos of this user. However, I found that not all videos are returned.

I tried to compare the videos that are returned with the ones that are not returned, but I could not find anything special about the none returned ones.

I am testing on the Google's developer console. Not tried in other ways.

## Update

If I play with the **publishedAfter** criteria, at some values, the search results *says* **totalResults=2**, but in the **items** field, only one result is returned. Is it a joke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [youtube.playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list) to get the playlistId(s) for the channel you are looking at. Then use [youtube.playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list) to get all videos for those playlists.

Comment: **youtube.playlists.list** returns empty results.

Comment: Assume the playlist(s) is/are public?

Comment: actually the account did not define any **channel**, nor **playlist**.

Comment: OK - so the only thing you have is a username?

Comment: yep. I use the username to find a *channelId*, even though the account did not define a channel.

Comment: I think you get a channel by default. If you use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list and set part=contentDetails and forUsername to the user name you should get a channelId back and a list of playlists (including uploads normally).